# Launch main activity if activity stack is empty

Tags: android, android-activity

I have one activity which can be launched from several other activites, along with url filter intents.

On this activity I use the home icon in the actionbar as a back button, bringing the user back to the previous activity (and not as a "home" action). For now I do this by calling the finish() function. This works fine when working from within the application.

However, if launching the activity by an url filter intent, I want the home icon to bring the user to the main activity. Obviously, calling finish() will just close the activity.

So my question is, is there a way to check whether my application stack is empty and then launch the main acivity if true? Or am I attacking this the wrong way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If your app is launched via url intent filter and it creates its own task, then you can use

```
if (isTaskRoot()) {
    // This activity is at root of task, so launch main activity
} else {
    // This activity isn't at root of task, so just finish()
}
```

**EDIT: Added another possible method**

If your app is launched into an existing task when it is launched via URL intent filter, then you can do something like the following:

When you launch your activity from other activities in your application, add an EXTRA to the Intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("internal", "true");
startActivity(intent);
```

When your activity gets launched it can then check for the presence or absence of the EXTRA in the Intent to determine whether it was launched internally or via URL intent-filter, like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent.hasExtra("internal")) {
    // Launched internally
} else {
    // Launched via intent-filter
}
```

Comment: Seemed like a nice solution, but sadly it doesn't work. isTaskRoot() returns false in both situations. I guess I need it to work when it's not launching a new task aswell (i.e. app is running in background already?). I can't wrap my head around the activity/task handling..

Comment: Edited my answer to add another method you can use since your activity is obviously launched into an existing task.

Comment: That should of course work, but I would presume a cleaner solution exists? Gmail app and others implement similar behaviour. Either way, it will have to do. Thank you!

Comment: There are other ways. You can declare your activity that has the URL intent-filter as `launchMode="singleTask"`, in that case your activity will be started in a new task and you can use the first method I suggested. Or, you can declare a different Activity that is started via URL intent-filter so that you know where you are coming from.